# Flyouts in Top Toolbar navigation SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I followed the instructions to change the navigation tool bar to flyouts - no problem and it looks great! The problem I am having is, when I click a tab, the Home tab is highlighted and the selected tab is not. What do I need to do to have the selected tab highlighted so it's obvious what page I am on? Please keep in mind, I am using SharePoint Foundation.